# When can there be an ambiguous parse using reads?

Tags: parsing, haskell

The [Standard Haskell Classes](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/stdclasses.html) page says the following about `reads :: (Read a) => String -> [(a,String)]`:

> Normally, a parser returns a singleton list, containing a value of
>   type a that was read from the input string and the remaining string
>   that follows what was parsed. If no parse was possible, however, the
>   result is the empty list, and if there is more than one possible parse
>   (an ambiguity), the resulting list contains more than one pair.

Under what situations or examples does this ambiguity manifest?

Comment: think of `data Foo = F | Fo | Foo deriving (Show,Read)` and `reads "FooBar" :: [(Foo,String)]`

Comment: @epsilonhalbe ... sadly it will not work this way (`reads "FooBar" :: ...` will yield `[]`)

Comment: Great question! I'd guess that this never happens in standard library types, but `reads` still accounts for the possibility that a user might want to define a non "prefix code" representation for their own types. (?) IMHO, I find `readMaybe` more useful in practice.

Comment: Probably it is related to `lex` returning `[(String, String)]` which raises a similar question: in which cases can the lexer produce more than one pair? I checked the `lex` source, but it uses a parsing combinator library with a monad with alternation, so it's not obvious.

Comment: after thinking a bit about this (usually you'll want `Read` as the *left* inverse to `Show` - at least I like to think about it this way) I think it does not make much sense to have one with multiple *possibilities* and I have the feeling that this one might come from a time when `[a]` was considered the *better* `Maybe a` (as it works so nicely with list comprehensions ;) )... but this is just a wild guess on my part

Comment: So, historical wart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Text.Read

data Foo = Bar Int | Baz Double deriving Show

instance Read Foo where 
    readPrec = fmap Bar readPrec +++ fmap Baz readPrec
```

In this example, the parser tries to parse `Int` and `Double`. If it can be parsed for both, the parser returns two values.

Resulting in:

```
> read "4" :: Foo
*** Exception: Prelude.read: ambiguous parse
```

and

```
> reads "4" :: [(Foo,String)]
[(Bar 4,""),(Baz 4.0,"")]
```

The easiest way here to fix ambiguity is to select one parse by replacing the [choice operator `+++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadPrec.html#g:3) with the [selective choice `<++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadPrec.html#g:3).